# How to check if a stripe standalone account is verified?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, account, stripe-connect

Is there a way in php to check if a standalone account connected to your stripe application is verified (meaning that a user has confirmed his identity uploading an id document approved by stripe)?

Comment: can you please tell me how we can check which users are connected to our standalone stripe application kindly please help me on this...

Answer (score 2):

Simply [retrieve the account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#retrieve_account):

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve("acct_...");
```

You can then check the following boolean attributes:

`$account->details_submitted`: Whether or not account details have been submitted yet. Standalone accounts cannot receive transfers before this is true.

`$account->charges_enabled`: Whether or not the account can create live charges

`$account->transfers_enabled`: Whether or not Stripe will send automatic transfers for this account. This is only false when Stripe is waiting for additional information from the account holder.

(Source: description of the [account object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#account_object).)

Comment: I've already done that, but it seems they guarantee only if account is activated: using an account I created without any uploaded id document they were all true. I used development environment but I guess using live would be the same.